# jquery get id of input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

i need to get the id of a input that's inside a span of a sharepoint list.
it looks like the code below.

```
<tr id="idEstablishmentRow">
<td class="ms-formbody" vAlign="top">
<span dir="none">
<span style="vertical-align: middle;">
<input type='text' id='hello' />
</span>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

now i want to get the id of the input.
i have tried:

```
    var _test = $('#idEstablishmentRow').find('td.ms-formbody');
    var _test1 = _test.find('span.style');

    var _test2 = _test1.find('input');
    var _test3 = _test2.attr('id');
    alert(_test3);
    alert(_test2);
```

but it didn't work.
could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 13):

You might want this :

```
var id = $('#idEstablishmentRow td.ms-formbody span input').attr('id');
```

But as your HTML doesn't have any element whose id is `idEstablishmentRow`, it's hard to be sure of what you exactly want.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/9MCnX/)

Comment: i have a sharepoint list with alot of trs/tds, the idestablishmentrow is the id of the row forgot to put it in sorry.

Comment: So that should work. Maybe you want to replace `td` with `td.ms-formbody` too, depending on your real HTML.

Comment: i have uploaded the actual code. i need the id of the input, if i use your code and try to alert it it says undefined

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputId = $("span input").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet does not work because of this selector : `var _test1 = _test.find('span.style');`

When doing this, you try to find a span with the css class "style" not the html attribute style. And thus `_test1` is empty.

You can do the following to fix it : `var _test1 = _test.find('span[style]');`

Though its not really a good selector, because it is most likely going to break if you change the css to remove it from inline.

- You could add a class to the span `<span class="aclass"></span>`. And this way you can select it by the following selector : `var _test1 = _test.find('span.aclass');`
- You could also select it in other ways like `var _test1 = _test.find('span:nth-child(2)');` if it's always the second child.

*These are only two of the multiple possible solutions to go with your `_test2` and `_test3`*

- You can also try to select all spans with inputs in it with `var _test1 = _test.find('span input');` or `_test.find('span').children('input')`. Then you can do your `_test3`.

---

**Note that you can regroup the selector in 1 line :**

This has the advantage of not having to put a class on the span since you actually not only query for the span but for a span WITH an input in it.

```
$('tr#idEstablishmentRow td.ms-formbody span input');

//or to get the id directly
$('tr#idEstablishmentRow td.ms-formbody span input').attr('id');
```