# jQuery Action Origination

Tags: jquery

I have the class of .addy applied to multiple inputs. I don't want to write a bunch of functions with the same code, so I would like to have `if` statements inside that tell function which parts to execute. This depends on where the action originates from: input#address1 or input#address2.

I need help with my `if` statement, please. How can I tell the function whether the #address1 or #address2 was where request originated?

```
$("input.addy").on('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var uid = $('form#data input[name=user_id]').val();
    var bid = $('form#data input[name=business_id]').val();
    if () { // If the change was made to input#address1, do the below
        var address1 = this.value;
        var data = {user_id: uid, business_id: bid, address1: address1};
        $.ajax({
            url: '/business/assignment/saveaddressone',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: data,
            success: update
        })
    }
    if () { // If the change was made to input#address2, do the below

        // Here is address2 code
    }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897768/jquery-get-id-of-input-field and use $(this) instead.

Comment: Not too sure on what exactly you're trying to do

Comment: @HugoSousa, that doesn't help thanks though

Comment: Just compare the ids with `$(this).attr ("id") == "address1"`

Comment: thanks @YerkoPalma - that was it! too easy

Comment: @webwrks Well, that was my suggestion on the first comment and you said it didn't work.

Comment: I'll comment that I *really* dislike `$(this)` use [`$(e.target)`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) instead. Not only is `this` confusing, but the value of it can change when you refactor your code and you have to be *very* careful to know the exact rules for `this` binding. Get rid of that cognitive load entirely, avoid `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check the `id` of the changed `input`, which you can access with `$(this).attr(id)`.

```
$("input.addy").on('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var uid = $('form#data input[name=user_id]').val();
    var bid = $('form#data input[name=business_id]').val();
    if ($(this).attr('id') == "address1") { //if the change was made to input#address1, do the below
        var address1 = this.value;
        var data = {user_id: uid, business_id: bid, address1: address1};
        $.ajax({
            url:'/business/assignment/saveaddressone',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType:'JSON',
            data:data,
            success: update
        })
    } 
    if ($(this).attr('id') == "address2") { //if the change was made to input#address2, do the below
        //here is address2 code
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 e.target.id === 'address1'
```

or

```
 $(e.target).is('#address1')
```

But, rather than use an if, this is exactly where you would use a function that returns another function.

```
function doStuff(wrappedFunctionality) { return function doStuff(e) {
   var $el = $(e.target);
   //do common stuff here
   wrappedFunctionality($el);
   //do more common stuff
} }

$('#address1').on('change', doStuff(function($el) {
   //do address1 specific things
}))

$('#address2').on('change', doStuff(function($el) {
   //do address2 specific things
}))
```

Obviously give functions good names that reflect what they're actually doing, not `doStuff` and `wrappedFunctionality`.

[Learn how to write composable functions](https://leanpub.com/javascript-allonge), it is the absolute heart of how to write idiomatic js.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ID of the `input.addy` that has been changed?

```
if($(this).attr('id') == "address1") {
    // it is input#address1
    ...
} else if ($(this).attr('id') == "address2") {
    // it is input#address2
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why wrap this in jquery? you can do this.id or e.target.id

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I am a jQuery fan :)

Comment: Even then, prop is more appropriate than attr here